# winforms-modernui controlbox displays incorrectly

Tags: c#, winforms, microsoft-metro

I am using [winforms-modernui](https://github.com/viperneo/winforms-modernui) in my desktop App.
I added winforms-modernui via Packet Manager Console. Everything works fine except that controlbox buttons are displayed incorrectly:

[image]

I did not found a solution yet. Any clues why this can be happening? Missing resource, reference?

I'm using VS Express 2012, Win8, .NET 4.5

Comment: You should not use such a buggy UI lib, try fixing it may help you **temporarily** and will possibly annoy you at some time in future.

Comment: "winforms modern UI" - there is no such thing. Use WPF instead.

Comment: @HighCore If I could I'd sure used WPF. The question is how to solve the problem with the existing winform-modernui NuGet Package.

Comment: @semyon you don't. winforms doesn't support "Modern UIs". That's the whole point. If you're forced to winforms, you need to stick to the default, ugly, Windows 3.1-like stuff. There is no customizability. There is no `Rich` UI. Only `poor` UI.